# CSV and SQLITE PANDAS WITH DIFFERENT Columns and Values

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv

I imported a csv file into Python and tried using SQLLite. But when I created the table, the columns and values were changed. For example, in the overall column the values "asin" appeared. The reviewerID column received the values "overall" and so on.
How to fix it?

```
class csvrd(object):
    def csvFile(self):

        self.readFile('reviews.csv')

    def readFile(self, filename):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('amazonReviews.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()             
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amazonReviews(reviewerID varchar, asin INT,reviewerName varchar,reviewText varchar, overall INT,summary varchar,unixReviewTime INTEGER,reviewTime INTEGER,helpful INT,total INT)""")

        filename.encode('utf-8')
        print("Amazon Reviews table executed")
        with open(filename) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for field in reader:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO amazonReviews VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", field)

        print("CSV Loaded into SQLite")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

c = csvrd().csvFile()


con = sqlite3.connect('amazonReviews.db')

pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM amazonReviews LIMIT 5", con)
```

EXPECTED:

```
    reviewerID  asin    reviewerName    reviewText  overall summary unixReviewTime  reviewTime  helpful total
0   A1EE2E3N7PW666  B000GFDAUG  Aaron L. Allen "Orgazmo1009"    CA Lewsi' review should be removed. he's revie...   5   Stupid  1202256000  02 6, 2008  0   0
1   AGZ8SM1BGK3CK   B000GFDAUG  Mind's Clay I truly love the humor of South Park. It's soc...   5   "More Moist Than Should Be" Humor   1198195200  12 21, 2007 1   1
```

ACTUAL:

```
    asin    overall reviewText  reviewTime  reviewerID  reviewerName    summary unixReviewTime  helpful total
0   A1EE2E3N7PW666  B000GFDAUG  Aaron L. Allen "Orgazmo1009"    CA Lewsi' review should be removed. he's revie...   5   Stupid  1202256000  02 6, 2008  0   0
1   AGZ8SM1BGK3CK   B000GFDAUG  Mind's Clay I truly love the humor of South Park. It's soc...   5   "More Moist Than Should Be" Humor   1198195200  12 21, 2007 1   1[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the table already exists with the columns in the "ACTUAL" result order. Table will not be created because of "IF NOT EXISTS" in the "CREATE" sql. The data will be loaded without "type" complaint because of manifest typing.